# Threadpool - How to call a method (with params) in the main thread from a worker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I'm working through my first attempt to thread an application. The app works with a large data set that is split up into manageable chunks which are stored on disk, so the entire data set never has to reside in memory all at once. Instead, a subset of the data can be loaded piecemeal as needed. These chunks were previously being loaded one after the other in the main thread. Of course, this would effectively pause all GUI and other operation until the data was fully loaded.

So I decided to look into threading, and do my loading while the app continues to function normally. I was able to get the basic concept working with a ThreadPool by doing something along the lines of the pseudo-code below:

```
public class MyApp
{
    List<int> listOfIndiciesToBeLoaded; //This list gets updated based on user input
    Dictionary<int,Stuff> loadedStuff = new Dictionary<int,Stuff>();

    //The main thread queues items to be loaded by the ThreadPool
    void QueueUpLoads()
    {
        foreach(int index in listOfIndiciesToBeLoaded)
        {
            if(!loadedStuff.ContainsKey(index))
                loadedStuff.Add(index,new Stuff());

            LoadInfo loadInfo = new LoadInfo(index); 
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(LoadStuff, loadInfo);
        }
    }

    //LoadStuff is called from the worker threads
    public void LoadStuff(System.Object loadInfoObject)
    {
        LoadInfo loadInfo = loadInfoObject as LoadInfo;
        int index = loadInfo.index;

        int[] loadedValues = LoadValuesAtIndex(index); /* here I do my loading and ...*/

        //Then I put the loaded data in the corresponding entry in the dictionary
        loadedStuff[index].values = loadedValues;
        //Now it is accessible from the main thread and it is flagged as loaded
        loadedStuff[index].loaded = true;
    }   
}

public class Stuff
{
    //As an example lets say the data being loaded is an array of ints
    int[] values;
    bool loaded = false;
}

//a class derived from System.Object to be passed via ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
public class LoadInfo : System.Object
{
    public int index;

    public LoadInfo(int index)
    {
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

This is very primitive compared to the quite involved examples I've come across while trying to learn this stuff in the past few days. Sure, it loads the data concurrently and stuffs it into a dictionary accessible from the main thread, but it also leaves me with a crucial problem. I need the main thread to be notified when an item is loaded and which item it is so that the new data can be processed and displayed. Ideally, I'd like to have each completed load call a function on the main thread and provide it the index and newly loaded data as parameters. I understand that I can't just call functions on the main thread from multiple other threads running concurrently. They have to be queued up in some way for the main thread to run them when it is not doing something else. But this is where my current understanding of thread communication falls off.

I've read over a few in-depth explanations of how events and delegates can be set up using Control.Invoke(delegate) when working with Windows Forms. But I'm not working with Windows Forms and haven't been able to apply these ideas. I suppose I need a more universal approach that doesn't depend on the Control class. If you do respond, please be detailed and maybe use some of the naming in my pseudo-code. That way it will be easier for me to follow. Threading appears to be a pretty deep topic, and I'm just coming to grips with the basics. Also please feel free to make suggestions on how I can refine my question to be more clear.

Comment: Why `loadInfoObject as pv_LoadInfo`?

Comment: my bad - edited to fix

Comment: You might want to have a look on `await` / `async` if you're on .NET FW 4.5. Also, your code is not thread-safe - `Dictionary<K, V>` is *not* thread-safe - if you need to share that dictionary, use `ConcurrentDictionary<K, V>` instead. What GUI *are* you using? WPF also has Invoke (look at `Dispatcher`). If your "GUI" is a console, it gets trickier, you'll need to incorporate a message queue (probably `ConcurrentQueue<T>`) in your main loop and check it periodically - if it has data, dequeue and process it immediately.

Comment: .NET 3.5ish. I should be able to get the dictionary to be filled from the main thread if I get the worker threads sending the loaded data to a function on the main thread in the way I described.

Comment: You might be able to use `BackgroundWorker` to help, if objects on the worker thread don't require STA threading (typically COM objects). Like `QueueUserWorkItem`, this uses the .NET thread pool whose threads are MTA threaded. Then use the overload of `ReportProgress` that takes an `Object` param to pass a `Stuff` instance to the main thread (the `int` parameter need not be a real 'progress' value, it could be the index value).

Comment: Note: `BackgroundWorker` will save you time if you want a quick solution but it's definitely worth getting to know `async/await` and `SynchronizationContext`, as others have suggested.

Comment: I'm attempting an implementation with SynchronizationContext atm. I think this may be the best approach for my case, but I'm still working through it.

Comment: BTW. Using async/await seems like the most convenient approach, except I have to work in an older version of .net than 4.5. From what I've read and tried so far, it looks like I may have to extend my own version of SnchronizationContext, as per part2 of the article posted in Lummo's answer. It looks like this is mainly just a way of blackboxing a queue of delegate calls from thread to thread. Although if this is a good way to do it, I'm kind of surprised that I haven't been able to find a universal implementation out there so far.

Comment: The MSDN article [It's all about the SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx), also worth reading, states, "the ActionThread class of the Nito.Async library (nitoasync.codeplex.com) may be used as a general-purpose SynchronizationContext implementation."

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't using a GUI framework with some kind of dispatcher or GUI thread (like WPF or WinForms) then you'll have to do this manually.

One way to do this is to use a SynchronizationContext.
It's somewhat tricky to manage but there are a few articles which go into how it works and how can you make your own:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32113/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-II

However I would also consider using either a single 'DictionaryChanged' boolean which is regularly checked by your 'main thread' (when it is idle) to indicate that the dictionary is changed. The flag could then be reset on the main thread to indicate that this has been handled. Keep in mind that you'll need to do some locking there.

You could also queue messages using a thread safe queue which is written by the background thread and read from the main thread if a simple variable is not sufficient. This is essentially what most dispatcher implementations are actually doing under the hood.

Comment: Aw yeah. SynchronizationContext might just be the ticket. Well written info, too. I'll have to spend some time messing with it.